# Adding tooltip to SVG elements with text from an array

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have multiple SVG circles and would like each to have unique text appear in a tooltip on hover.

I will be creating my SVG elements in Adobe Illustrator, so need a way to bind text for the tooltip to the id's of the SVGs.

Below I have tried to do this by creating an array with object "color: white" matching the name of the SVG circle id="#white" How can I bind this data to my tooltip?

```js
var tooltipText = [
  {"color":"white", "text":"About white"}, 
  {"color":"black", "text":"About black"} 
]
     
var tooltip = d3.select('.tooltip').text(function(d) {return tooltipText}) 
     
d3.select('#white')
  .on("mouseover", function(){
    return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
  })
  .on("mousemove", function(){
    return tooltip
    .style("top",(d3.event.pageY+10)+"px")
    .style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(){
    return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
  });
```

```css
      .container {
        position: relative;
      }
    
      .tooltip {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 200px;
        visibility: hidden;
        background: white;
      }
      
      #white {
        fill: white;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 2px
      }
      
      #black {
        fill: black
      }
      
      circle:hover {
        stroke: green; !important
        fill: orange;
        stroke-width: 2px
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <svg>
    <g id="selection">
   <circle id="white" class="st0" cx="49.2" cy="49.2" r="48.7"/>
   <circle id="black" class="st1" cx="128.4" cy="49.2" r="48.7"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="tooltip"></div>
```

Comment: you can have a seperate svg component... that contains the tooltip, and move it/change text around on hover. Or you can also have a text component inside of eacg svg and control its visibility/text on hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we get the Id of the circle with this line inside your `mousemove`:

```
var thisId = d3.select(this).attr("id");
```

Then, we loop through your array and get the corresponding value:

```
var index;
for(var i = 0; i < tooltipText.length; i++){
    if(tooltipText[i].color == thisId){
        index= i
    }
};
tooltip.html(tooltipText[index].text)
```

Here is your updated snippet:

```js
var tooltipText = [
{"color":"white", "text":"About white"}, 
{"color":"black", "text":"About black"} 
]
     
var tooltip = d3.select('.tooltip').text(function(d) {return tooltipText}) 
     
d3.selectAll("circle")
  .on("mousemove", function(d){
    var thisId = d3.select(this).attr("id");
    var index;
    for(var i = 0; i < tooltipText.length; i++){
        if(tooltipText[i].color == thisId){ index= i}
    };
    tooltip.html(tooltipText[index].text)
    .style("visibility", "visible")
    .style("top",(d3.event.pageY+10)+"px")
    .style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(){
    return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
  });
```

```css
      .container {
        position: relative;
      }
    
      .tooltip {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 200px;
        visibility: hidden;
        background: white;
      }
      
      #white {
        fill: white;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 2px
      }
      
      #black {
        fill: black
      }
      
      circle:hover {
        stroke: green; !important
        fill: orange;
        stroke-width: 2px
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <svg>
    <g id="selection">
   <circle id="white" class="st0" cx="49.2" cy="49.2" r="48.7"/>
   <circle id="black" class="st1" cx="128.4" cy="49.2" r="48.7"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="tooltip"></div>
```